# Next Number Generate in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm having a below kind of a list in sql table column.

```
IT-001
IT-002
IT-003
IT-004
```

I want to generate the next code using LINQ. Currently i'm using below code. I want to know that is it possible to achieve it using pure LINQ query without using C# code. If yes how?

```
 private StockDataClassesDataContext dc;

        public string getNextItemCode()
        {
            dc = new StockDataClassesDataContext();

            List<string> code = (from tbItem in dc.tblItems
                                select tbItem.ItemCode).ToList<string>();


            List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();

            foreach (string item in code)
            {
                string[] arr = item.Split('-');

                Numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(arr[1]));

            }

            int maxNumber = 0;

            maxNumber = Numbers.Count > 0 ? Numbers.Max() : 0;

            int nextNumber = maxNumber + 1;

            string itemCode = "IT-"+nextNumber;

            return itemCode;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the database to find the last one by sorting on that field and getting Last()?  Or if you really are sure they are sequential why not just Count() them, add one and create the new record?  Of course none of this will work if you have two writers.

Comment: Why would you want to use LINQ for this? `getNextItemCode()` is something that needs to be abstracted anyways so the details are within the method so why make it harder to add error handling / harder to debug just for the sake of using LINQ? Just because LINQ can be used to solve a lot of problems doesn't mean it should or it's the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string nextCode = dc.tblItems.Count()==0 ? "IT-001" : // if it's empty, start with IT-001
    "IT-" +
    (int.Parse(dc.tblItems.OrderByDescending(i=>i.ItemCode) // order by code descending
                          .First() // get first one (last code)
                          .ItemCode.Split('-')[1]) // get only the number part
     +1).ToString("000") // add 1 and format with 3 digits
```

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to make a seperate field for number in database. Like SeqNo column. By this you can easily generate the next number and also it is easy to store.

Answer (score 2):

This way of item code generate will fail if many readers connect at ones and they will end up with same item code.

Why don't you change the logic to avoid all those issues?

You can have auto increment field and separate column for item code text part. That also can store in separate table if you have many sub codes like that and adding foreign key  in main table.

Now you don't worry about how to generate next code, because database will increment id number automatically. When you want to display item code you can join text part and id part.

Comment: Actually the number generation is done when saving the record and the transaction is handled so there is no risk of getting the same ID by multiple users.Thanks for your idea i should relay try that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could do the same thing without all of the lists. Try this:

```
public string getNextItemCode()
{
    dc = new StockDataClassesDataContext();

    var nextNumber = 
        (from tbItem in dc.tblItems
         select tbItem.ItemCode)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(code => Convert.ToInt32(code.Substring(code.IndexOf("-") + 1))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Max() + 1;

    return "IT-" + nextNumber;
}
```

Depending on your Linq provider, you may be able to get away with doing the integer conversion in the query, like this:

```
public string getNextItemCode()
{
    dc = new StockDataClassesDataContext();

    var nextNumber = 
        (from tbItem in dc.tblItems
         let c = tbItem.ItemCode
         select Convert.ToInt32(c.Substring(c.IndexOf("-") + 1))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Max() + 1;

    return "IT-" + nextNumber;
}
```

I based the final return value on your code, but as others have pointed out, this would produce incorrectly formatted strings (`IT-1` rather than `IT-001`). You should probably use a format string to make your life easier:

```
return "IT-" + nextNumber.ToString("D3");
// or
return string.Format("IT-{0:D3}", nextNumber);
```